# Sending email with Python having correct sending time

Tags: python, email, email-client

I'm sending email through an account with the following Python code:

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

def sendMail(target, subject, txt):

    fromaddr = 'my@test.com'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = target
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText("This is my text"))

    server = smtplib.SMTP('node01.mailserver.com', '587')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(fromaddr, 'mypassword')
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, target, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

This works quite well and I can receive the emails.

However, the timestamp which is displayed in my email client shows the time I downloaded the mail from the server and not time the email was actually send.

Is there a way how to correctly add the sending time to the email? I would assume that the sending time is not correctly set and that's the reason why the download time is displayed?
Or do I make other mistakes?

Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the headers of your e-mail do you see the "right time"? That header should be set automatically.

Comment: Ask the email client for the details of the message and the *actual headers*.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
...
import email.utils
...
msg['Date'] = email.utils.formatdate(localtime=True)
...
```